# How come Keepass and Lastpass don't recognize URL's?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keepass, lastpass

I have some domains that host, phpMyAdmin, roundcube, etc, but the services never seem to be able to recognize which is which.

With the old Firefox manager it always saw easily which was phpMyAdmin and which was roundcube, but it seems to mix up passwords now and just randomly give a password for any service that uses that domain.

Can Keepass and Lastpass not save full url's? I don't want to be bugged with my Cacti-password when I am trying to log in into Nagios. (/cacti, /nagios).

Answer (score 1):

This is the extension right?  It will store full urls.  But you should try storing a lower level domain instead. Or just link your login to the login screen that pops up.

http://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=42729

When the login comes up.  Type or copy and paste the relevant information.  Then under the Lastpass button, hit "Store form." It will save the form fields and their relevant data.

Keep in mind this isn't fool proof. I've had forms that change the textbox metadat daily, thus breaking the lastpass form fields detection. . .